# How to debug whether restarts are caused by software or hardware?

Tags: debian, hardware, reboot

A newly build Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux server suffers numerous restarts.

'`last -x`' output shows:

```
root     pts/0        192.168.254.11   Sat Dec 15 13:13   still logged in   
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 13:10 - 13:17  (00:06)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 13:10 - 13:17  (00:06)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 12:53 - 13:10  (00:17)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 12:53 - 13:17  (00:23)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 12:36 - 12:53  (00:17)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 12:36 - 13:17  (00:40)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 12:19 - 12:36  (00:17)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 12:19 - 13:17  (00:57)    
root     pts/0        192.168.254.11   Sat Dec 15 12:04 - crash  (00:14)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 12:01 - 12:19  (00:17)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 12:01 - 13:17  (01:15)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 11:44 - 12:01  (00:17)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 11:44 - 13:17  (01:32)    
root     pts/0        192.168.254.11   Sat Dec 15 11:36 - crash  (00:08)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 11:26 - 11:44  (00:18)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 11:26 - 13:17  (01:50)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 11:08 - 11:26  (00:17)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 11:08 - 13:17  (02:08)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 10:51 - 11:08  (00:17)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 10:51 - 13:17  (02:25)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 10:34 - 10:51  (00:17)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 10:34 - 13:17  (02:42)    
root     pts/0        192.168.254.11   Sat Dec 15 02:41 - crash  (07:53)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 02:32 - 10:34  (08:02)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 02:32 - 13:17  (10:45)    
runlevel (to lvl 0)   2.6.32-5-amd64   Sat Dec 15 02:12 - 02:32  (00:19)
```

Output of '`top`' command less then 0.1 seconds before a crash/reboot occurred:

```
top - 15:14:04 up 16 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.01
Tasks: 163 total,   1 running, 162 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.0%us,  8.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 91.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8191048k total,    87356k used,  8103692k free,     2432k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    20120k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                       
 2296 root      20   0 19072 1432 1032 R    9  0.0   0:10.25 top                                                                                                            
    1 root      20   0  8356  820  684 S    0  0.0   0:00.79 init                                                                                                           
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                       
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                                                    
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.03 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                    
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                                                                                                     
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1                                                                                                    
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                    
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1                                                                                                     
    9 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2
```

'`Sensors`' output in minute 16 shows:

```
temp1:       +37.0 C  (high = +60.0 C, hyst = +55.0 C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:       +75.0 C  (high = +95.0 C, hyst = +92.0 C)  sensor = diode
temp3:       +32.0 C  (high = +75.0 C, hyst = +70.0 C)  sensor = thermistor
```

**Update #2**:

- When running `top` the issue occurs often in the 16th minute of uptime.
- When having less load attached (60 instead of 74 SATA drives) to the Corsair 1050HX PSU the issue does never occur.
- Having 74 SATA drives connected, in minute 14 the "watts up?" meter all of a sudden starts measuring an increased power consumption value: 435 Watt instead of 326 Watt.
- The sudden power increase in minute 14 does also occur in other bpo.3 and bpo.4 kernel versions where storage modules are not loaded into the kernel (no /dev/sdb etc.)

**Update #3**: all drives are not partitioned, not formatted and not mounted except for one boot drive.

**Update #4**: the issue where Hitachi/Toshiba HDS5C drives are starting to consume more considerably - 5.34W instead of 3.5W without any read/write activity - more power after 15 minutes doesn't seem OS (Software) related because `cat /proc/diskstats | grep " sd"` returns 224 sectors read and 0 sectors written after boot, and that number stays identical when the power consumption starts spiking.

The question is how to find out whether these restarts are caused by:

- Software
- Hardware (for instance a short situation kicking in the over current protection on the power supply)
  ?

Comment: You should update this post , i suppose your issue solve in http://serverfault.com isn't it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More closely monitoring the system it's power consumption using a "watts up?" Watt meter lead to a stronger belief that these restarts were caused by an over current protection (OCP) on the power supply that kicks in.

Asking why the power consumption increase was happing 15 minutes after boot, lead to a serverfault answer that 15 minutes after boot all 74 drives might start running their automatic offline S.M.A.R.T. (Self-Monitoring, Analysis, and Reporting Technology of hard disk drives) tests at the same time.

Next try was to disable running automatic offline tests with: `smartctl --offlineauto=off /dev/sdx`. As now there are no more power consumption spikes neither restarts for already 20 hours, a preliminary conclusion is that the drive its setting to run periodic offline S.M.A.R.T. tests is the cause.

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't see your answer before adding my own, but if you see mine, you're *way* under spec on the power supply.

Answer (score 3):

First off, 72 hard drives is a lot (biggest machine I have is only 24... and has 1200W supplies) I hope you're using staggered spinup.

You're probably seeing the drives start an offline data collection. That would explain the increase in power usage. It also means that if you were to actually use the drives, you'd probably push the power consumption at least as high.

Your drive specification sheet says a peak of 2A on the 12V rail. Your power supply says it can do 87.5A on the 12V rail. So you could very easily exceed that, especially since other components want some of that. You may want to get a volt meter (and current meter if possible) on that rail, to see if that's whats happening.

I'm going to go ahead and guess the answer is "yes". You're running with a tiny supply compared to the number of drives. For example, a system builder we use makes a [45-drive JBOD with 1400W supplies](http://www.siliconmechanics.com/i19897/4u-45-drive-jbod-sas-sata.php), and you've got more drives still, and a computer as well. Of course, that JBOD is probably spec'd for 15K SAS drives. But you have an extra 27 drives.

### Debugging a software crash (which is probably isn't)

The main thing you want to try and find a software crash is to get kernel logs up to the last possible second. Your best bet is, if you have a serial port, to attach another machine and use the serial console (add console=/dev/ttyS0,57600 to the kernel command line). Your second-best is to use netconsole, which you can configure easily once the machine is booted (but before the 16 minutes are up):

First, on some other machine, run `nc -l -u -p 1234`. Then, on the always-crashing machine, `modprobe netconsole netconsole=@/eth0,1234@some-ip/`. You should see a few console messages immediately in the netcat window:

```
[508073.196581] console [netcon0] enabled
[508073.197026] netconsole: network logging started
```

Your timestamps will be much lower, of course.

Comment: The drive specification peak happens at cold boot. We are lucky that our Corsair 1050 Watt power supply has a 12V OCP that is measured to be above 122 Amp. Only once, we have had a protection kicking in during system start. The result is that automatically a new boot occurs, which is a warm boot requiring less startup current. Therefore I guess that our issue which happens roughly every 17 minutes, is not on the 12V but on the 5V rail.

Comment: @ProBackup I couldn't find specs on your PS's 5V rail, so I don't know. But yeah, could be. You need to figure out how to enable staggered spinup (may be a jumper on the drive), that'll solve your problems at cold boot.

Comment: We are not going to do staggered spin up, as the PSU in 99% of each boot is able the handle the start up peak currents. When we would need to, we time delay switching on the power on groups of 15 drives using a PCB and mechanical 16A relays. We have tested this and did see startup power consumption peaks drop from 1254 Watt to 1005 Watt when delaying power on of 15 drives for a few seconds.

Comment: @ProBackup Hmmm, if you can do staggered spin up with your drives, you can do that in software instead of hardware. Or even do it in three groups of 15, which should give you a very good safety margin, in exchange for an extra 8s or so of boot time. But it seems like you're really not engineering this for reliability...

Comment: There is no jumper on the drive for staggered spin-up according to the Hitachi Hard Disk Drive Specification revision 1.1, 28. February. 2011. But according to page 73 there is an interesting "Power-up in Standby feature set".

Comment: @ProBackup Power-up in Standby is what you're looking for. Then you have Linux (or your controller BIOS) have them move from standby to active a few disks at a time. That's staggered spinup.

Comment: (Well, I guess, looking into it more, there are two ways to accomplish staggered spinup. Power-up in standby is one of the two. Make sure your BIOS supports it, or don't enable it on the OS drives and then Linux should be able to handle it)

Comment: Setting `/sbin/hdparm -s1 --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing /dec/sdx` did reduce the startup power consumtion peak from 1206 Watt to 200 Watt. But now `modprobe mpt2sas` times out after 3 minutes and 51 seconds.

Comment: @ProBackup probably best to open a new question on that, but is it finding drives and just not finishing with all of them? Or does it fail to find any?

Comment: Also, http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.scsi/75915/ looks like it may be relevant.

Comment: IT does not find any drives. The new question is created at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58922/how-to-fix-mpt2sas-port-enable-failed-with-timeout

Answer (score 1):

As per your output of `last -x` , seems reboot every 17-18 minute, so you first need to check, is there any script or cron is set for reboot or not? If not then read below.

Hardware related error you can check in `dmesg | tail` or software related logs your can find in logs of that particular application which you are running in your server usually `tail -f /var/log/messages` or `tail -f /var/log/syslog` (debian based).

And if you want to quickly check is software issue or hardware issue, then you should check `top`.

```
hi  --  Hardware IRQ
          The amount of time the CPU has been servicing hardware interrupts.

si  --  Software Interrupts
          The amount of time the CPU has been servicing software interrupts.
```

[image]

Also you have to check %wa value in top, in case if there is issue with your hdd then this value will increase. So you can check using `hdparam -T /dev/sdx` and other tools. But this is not final, there may be lot of way to check the same.

Comment: I have found how to change the colors of top, but how the display individual cores in the summary?

Comment: Press 1 in when top is running....

Comment: As there is no shutdown message broadcasted and all values "%wa, %hi, %si" are 0.0%, I conclude that the issue is related to power supply / the power supply.

Comment: which apps are you running on this server ?
if there is power supply issue, then it will never shows in last -x output.
Did you check your CPU temperatures?

Comment: Yes, CPU temperature was checked and found to be in medium range. The power supply doesn't seem to be the issue. Something causes the drives to consume and stay consuming a lot more power (on the 5V output is my guess) in minute 14 after boot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the /var/log/messages

If you don't see the any shutdown or init 6 then the most probably cause is hardware. Otherwise it will be reboot initiated by some user.

Comment: The OP should do a `ls -ltr /var/log` and check the files shown at the last lines. Optionally I'd open a terminal from a remote pc and do `tail -f /var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check CPU temperature, you can check in syslog using below command :- 
`grep 'temperature' /var/log/syslog` 
if above command output is blank , then you have to install the `lm-sensors` package and run `sudo sensors-detect` choose YES to all YES/no questions. 
At the end of sensors-detect, a list of modules that needs to be loaded will displayed. 
Type "yes" to have sensors-detect insert those modules into /etc/modules, or edit /etc/modules yourself. 
Next, run `sudo service module-init-tools restart` This will read the changes you made to /etc/modules in step 3, and insert the new modules into the kernel. 
Next, you should test that lm-sensors works correctly. Run the `sensors` command and check if possible post output. 
i think you need to run this command after 15 minutes of your system boot time because every reboot between 17-18.

Comment: Sensors doesn't output medium temperatures. See main question.

Comment: have you checked syslog ?

Comment: There is nothing in `/var/log/syslog` after the last boot message: "`debian kernel: [   33.121545] sd 8:0:65:0: [sdbt] Attached SCSI disk`"